# Method has no supported translation in SQL in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to group by week in Linq.  I created helper method to define the week I want to group by but when running the code I get the error message:

*{"Method 'Int32 GetWeekNumber(System.DateTime)' has no supported translation to SQL."} System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}*

**My Linq query:**

```
var data = from trans in _dbc.MyStuff
       where
           SqlMethods.Like(trans.SEGMENT2, "00601") && SqlMethods.Like(trans.SEGMENT4, "%")
           &&
           trans.CREATION_DATE >= new DateTime(2013, 01, 01) &&
           trans.CREATION_DATE <= new DateTime(2013, 12, 31)
       group trans by new
       {
           DateYear = (int?)trans.CREATION_DATE.Value.Year,
           DateMonth = (int?)trans.CREATION_DATE.Value.Month,
           DateWeek = (int?)WeekStuff.GetWeekNumber(trans.CREATION_DATE.Value)
       }
           into g
           orderby
               g.Key.DateYear,
               g.Key.DateMonth,
               g.Key.DateWeek
           select new
           {
               DateYear = g.Key.DateYear ?? 0,
               DateMonth = g.Key.DateMonth ?? 0,
               DateWeek = g.Key.DateWeek ?? 0,
               Value = g.Sum(p => p.BASE_TRANSACTION_VALUE) ?? 0,
               Count = g.Sum(p => p.PRIMARY_QUANTITY) ?? 0,
               DateCreated = g.Min(p => p.CREATION_DATE) ?? DateTime.Now,
               Department = g.Min(p => p.SEGMENT2)
           };
```

**My Helper Method:**

```
    public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime date)
    {
        if (DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo != null)
        {
            Calendar cal = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
            return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Basically what I want to do is group also by week, how would I group using helper method (if I in fact will need a helper method to accomplish this)?

Comment: You can't use your methods in Linq. You need to translate it to SQL code somehow, and then use it

Comment: How would you do that work in SQL, if you were to write the SQL code directly?  If you can figure out how to do that, then consider trying to find a way to get LINQ to write that code.  If you can't, then LINQ probably can't either.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys.  I actually managed (with help) to write sql script that groups by weeks.  However I´ve had trouble converting that to Linq (but that would be a different question here on StackOverflow).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Create a function in SQL that does the calculation needed (note this depends upon the `@@DATEFIRST` setting on your SQL server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWeek](@dt datetime)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEPART( wk, @dt)
END
```

Step 2. In your data context class, add a function that does the same as your helper above, but marked as with the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute` attribute:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.GetWeek", IsComposable=true)]
public int GetWeekNumber([Parameter(Name="@dt", DbType="datetime")]DateTime date)
{
  Calendar cal = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
  return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

The `IsComposable=true` indicates it can be used as part of other queries (i.e. it's a function, not a stored procedure).

Step 3. Now change your query to use `dbc.GetWeekNumber` instead of `WeekStuff.GetWeekNumber`.

Alternatively, you could define the above method as:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.GetWeek", IsComposable=true)]
public int GetWeekNumber([Parameter(Name="@dt", DbType="datetime")]DateTime date)
{
  return (int)ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), date).ReturnValue;
}
```

That way, even when called outside of a query, it will hit the database rather than calculating it in the .NET code. This is slower (hitting a database for what we could calculate without it), but has the advantage of keeping the concept of first-day-of-week consistent between code that hits the database, and code that does not.

Comment: Wow!  That actually does the trick.  I didn´t realize using sql function and linq could go hand in hand like this.  I will need to check the settings for the sql server for the datefirst but this a great answer and works for me.  Thanks  :)

Comment: Just as Linq2SQL already knows how to map some .NET methods to SQL, and just as the `[Table]` attributes tell it how to map classes to tables, so the `[Function]` attribute tells it how to map new methods to SQL. You can also use it with stored procedures, but you then need `IsComposable=false` and you're much more limited in how you can use them (just as you're more limited in SQL itself using stored procedures rather than functions).

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a table-valued function, rather than scalar, define it as returning `IQueryable<SomeType>`, and you can do the same thing.

Comment: I can safely say that I´ve learned something today.  Thanks again @JonHanna  :)

Comment: NP. Also, if you can't change @@DateFirst on your server, you could add a constant number of days to the date in the function, so as to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ tries to convert your code to sql and run it on the server. Your custom method can't be translated to SQL, that's normal. You'll probably have to populate the result of LINQ query first and then to group it additionally using LINQ to objects.

Comment: Yes you are probably right.  I´ll probably need to do this with two separate objects.  It was worth checking here anyway. Thanks  :)